# How to generate OAuth 2.0 Access Token of Azure API in Jquery AJAX Method

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

How to generate Azure Access OAuth 2.0 token in Jquery AJAX method. I am able to get from Postman tool with the following headers.

Grant Type,
Callback URL,
Auth URL,
Access Token URL,
Client ID,
Client Secret,
Scope,
Client Authentication

Comment: There's a lot of information missing. Who is the token issuer? How does Postman work? etc

Comment: Using Microsoft Identity Provider and generating Access token using OAuth 2.0